# Positioning images on top of other

Tags: css, html, cordova

we are developing an cordova Ionic application. For front end we are using html css.
I want to position images to make http://s6.postimg.org/3jnxu7sr5/Home.png 
I am done with http://s6.postimg.org/92qhbfpsh/homw_Screen.png
But the remaining i am not able to bring the top image over the center button to achieve the target. I have uploaded my code here https://jsfiddle.net/sweety1112/p36jxhcd/3/embedded/result/ but fiddle has changed much of UI.

If some one could help that would be of much greatful.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="top">
   <h2 class="mid">Scan</h2>
   <img src='http://s6.postimg.org/wnc5qggup/home_scan.png'>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <img class="applyRotationLeft" src='http://s6.postimg.org/cnhaxjo0h/alphaeon_home_history.png'>
     <img class="centerButton" src='http://s6.postimg.org/szrcna2c1/start_btn.png'>
      <img class="applyRotationRight" src='http://s6.postimg.org/3orp3w029/home_config.png'>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
     <img src='http://s6.postimg.org/6gayuhykx/home_history.png'>


</div>
```

Regards,
Shraddha

Comment: `enter code here`, have you seen your question??

Comment: The code is in fiddle so didnt add code here.

Comment: I think you should use all images as `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you're going to be rotating the images, there's no need to have five seperate images, it's just more requests and more data usage, since you really need only two images.
If you use

```
transform-origin: x% x%;
```

and set it right at the center of the center button somehow, you only need to rotate each of the red things in increments of 90 degrees. I was able to do just that.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="centerButton">
        <img src='http://s6.postimg.org/szrcna2c1/start_btn.png'/>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="top rotate">
        <img src='http://s6.postimg.org/wnc5qggup/home_scan.png'/>
        <div>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left rotate">
        <img src='http://s6.postimg.org/wnc5qggup/home_scan.png'/>
        <div>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right rotate">
        <img src='http://s6.postimg.org/wnc5qggup/home_scan.png'/>
        <div>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom rotate">
        <img src='http://s6.postimg.org/wnc5qggup/home_scan.png'/>
        <div>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.rotate div{
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}
.centerButton img, .centerButton p{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:-50%;
    left:-50%;
    right:-50%;
    bottom:-50%;
    margin:auto;
}
.centerButton p{
    height:10%;
    text-align:center;
}
.centerButton{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:-50%;
    left:-50%;
    right:-50%;
    bottom:-50%;
}
.rotate img{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.rotate{
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
    position:absolute;
    width:72%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 70% 105%;
    transform-origin: 70% 105%;
}
.container .bottom, .bottom p{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.container .left, .right div p{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.container .right, .left div p{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.container{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
.rotate div p{
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.rotate div p{
    top:20%;
    left:20%;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awpeuk7v/) and [another](http://jsfiddle.net/awpeuk7v/1/) I think is a little bit cooler.

NOTE: I only used `-webkit-` prefix in my fiddle, so you may need to change that in your browser

EDIT: Edited to add what OP asked for in comments

Comment: Thanks a lot Olumide!!!  Second one is really cool but we want a mobile app so hover couldnt be used.

Comment: I want to position text on top of images Home, History, Notification, Setting  Can you please help me with same? If i use z-index its not super imposing. And all alignment is changing.

Comment: position: absolute; is also not working.    .overlayHistoryText{
 position: absolute;
 top:100px;
 left: 30px;
 color: black;
 }    In this case it is coming on first image but going behind. Not showing on top of image.

Comment: Also above is working if container is given in px. But if i want it in percent since i dont know the width and height then items seems to be misplaced.

Comment: Sweety I changed it up a bit for the text buttons. The whole thing was made to resize with the size of the container, as long as .container remains a square. You could technically use percent to size the container, but the container still has to remain a square, and if the parent of the container isn't a square it'll be dificult to make container a square with only percentages.

Answer (score 1):

Place the entire image inside one `div` container. Give each of the five pieces their own `id=""`. Use `#` to call each id in your css file, put `position:relative` in all five and use `top` `right` `bottom` & `left` with px values to maneuver all the pieces into place.